# in caffe/build/tools what does the cyan files mean? where are there corresponding source code?

Tags: makefile, caffe

This is my **ls** result under $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools:
[image]

I was wondering what does the cyan files mean?
FYI, this is my **ls -al** result:
[image]

a few more question:

- where does the **.bin .o .d** files come from?
- what's there corresponding source code(for example the
  **convert_imageset** files)?
- what is the **arrow** between the **cyan file** and the **green .bin
  file**?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Files are coloured differently in your terminal output to help identify their type. The arrow denotes a symlink, so it's pointing to the actual file it represents.

Comment: you can find the sources at [`$CAFFE_ROOT/tools`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/tools)

Comment: Thank you Simon, Thank you Shai! Great Answers